# WooCommerce: Add product to cart with override price cart and quick cart at the top?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try with this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
   $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
 }
```

But this updates only the cart. But still in the quick cart icon at the top it displays actual product price. Any solutions?

Comment: You can try http://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/

Comment: This updates only the cart. But still in the quick cart icon at the top it displays actual product price.....